# log4net AdoNetAppender in .Net core 2.0 not supported?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.0, log4net-appender, adonetappender

I'm implementing log4net **AdoNetAppender** in **asp.net core 2.0**, but I guess it is not supporting. I have implemented log4net **RollingFileAppender** in core 2.0 & it worked successfully using log4.net config. So, if log4net AdoNetAppender is not supporting in core 2.0, is there any other way to insert logs to sql database in core 2.0?

Thank you

Answer (score 9):

I faced the same issue and solved using this nuget package in .net core solution

https://www.nuget.org/packages/MicroKnights.Log4NetAdoNetAppender

You can find more information about how to set this up on

https://github.com/microknights/Log4NetAdoNetAppender

Other option could be referring to the implementation in https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/logging/log4net/tags/log4net-1_2_9/src/Appender/AdoNetAppender.cs

Comment: using 3d party tool to using 3d party tool

Comment: @Pr.Dumbledor Its an answer which solves the problem which Vishal is facing. I have given other option as well.

Comment: it seems nice but seems lacking some features. like i wanted to filterout some message on base of certain property but not able to succeed . check https://github.com/microknights/Log4NetAdoNetAppender/issues/13

Comment: A followup on @KamranShahid comment. The Log4NetAdoNetAppender for .net core/standard is working just fine. However If you need to do filters on custom fields from the appender, you need to write a custom filter. The is general for log4net, and the recipe can be found in the provided link

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I've fixed it in the following way:

Add *log4net.config.xml* file to the ASP.NET Core project with appenders. In this file for **AdoNetAppender** you can specify `connectionString` or `connectionStringName` but it doesn't make sense because the connection will be `null`.

So, add connection string to *appsettings.json* instead

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
   "Log": "Data Source=localhost\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Log.Database;User ID=sa;Password=;MultipleActiveResultSets=True"
}
```

Then configure

```
ILoggerRepository logRepository = log4net.LogManager.GetRepository(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
XmlConfigurator.Configure(logRepository, new FileInfo("log4net.config"));\
```

and assign connection string manually

```
ILog _databaseLogger = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger("DBLogger");
var repository = _databaseLogger?.Logger.Repository;
if (repository != null) 
{
    _adoAppender = repository.GetAppenders()
        .FirstOrDefault(a => a is AdoNetAppender) as AdoNetAppender;

    if (_adoAppender != null && string.IsNullOrEmpty(_adoAppender.ConnectionStringName)) 
    {
        _adoAppender.ConnectionString = "some connection string from appsettings.json";
        _adoAppender.ActivateOptions();
    }
}
```

The [`ActivateOptions()`](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/html/M_log4net_Appender_AdoNetAppender_ActivateOptions.htm) calls for reinitialize the appender.

Comment: log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender is not supported in .net core 2.0 until now.

Comment: @prashant what are you talking about? I'm using this code in project that targeting to .netcoreapp2.0 but of course package of log4net is targeting on 461. Everything works fine with that workaround

Comment: @RomanMarusyk Thanks works fine 
if you edit your answer maybe   @ prashant will know what do you mean,
I had to add AdoNetAppender Class and call it from my own application and your code works perfectly

Comment: You can do the same as what id proposed here by adding <connectionString value="your connection string so something like Data Source=..."/> to the xml file. connectionStringName is as noted useless